# IBATIS query where column contains exact String

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

I'm trying to create a query that will return everything containing a exact string in a specific column. It should return `x = "create query"` when I search for `create` or `query`, but not return anything when I search for `reate` or `uer`.

I need the equivalent of:

```
select * 
from table 
where column_name ~* \ycreate\y
```

and where I will replace create with a passed parameter. I see this works if I hardcode the value, but I was not able to pass it from a method, this is the code I tried:

```
@Select({SELECT * from table where column_name ~* '\\y' || #{valuePassedFromMethod} || '\\y'"})
List<String> methodName(@Param("valuePassedFromMethod") String valuePassedFromMethod);
```

I don't have a lot of experience and I was not able to find the problem, I would appreciate if somebody will help me fix this.

Comment: What error are you getting from the above?

Comment: The error sayis that it espects a boolean, not a string. When I hardcode a value instead of passing it from the method it works with string

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the expression `column_name ~* '\\y' || #{valuePassedFromMethod} || '\\y'`  is being evaluated from left to right, since all operators have the same precedence. You can see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/sql-precedence.html) that all the operators involved fall in the "all other native and user-defined operators" category, and thus they have the same precedence.

`column_name ~* '\\y'` returns true, and the subsequent concatenations return a text. So your query ends up looking like `SELECT * FROM unl_unit WHERE 'truecreate\y'`, assuming you are looking for the string `create`. You can see now how the WHERE clause in fact complains about receiving a text instead of a boolean. You can simply enclose the search pattern with parentheses to avoid this.

```
@Select({SELECT * from table where column_name ~* '(\\y' || #{valuePassedFromMethod} || '\\y')"})
List<String> methodName(@Param("valuePassedFromMethod") String valuePassedFromMethod);
```

That being said, I don't think the regex you are using actually reflects the search you are trying to achieve. The \y means start/end of string, so you are actually searching for the exact string 'create'. If you want to search for strings containing `create`, you should do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM unl_unit WHERE unlun_name like '%' || 'create' || '%';
```

And the method would be:

```
@Select({SELECT * from table where column_name LIKE '%' || #{valuePassedFromMethod} || '%'"})
List<String> methodName(@Param("valuePassedFromMethod") String valuePassedFromMethod);
```

Notice how you don't even need the parentheses here, since the LIKE operator has a lower precedence than the concatenation operators.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My previous approach was as you recommended, but this is not good for me because it will find other things I don't need contained inside a word. I need to return only if a exact word is contained in a string, delimited by spaces. For example in "create query" it should return if I search for create or query, but not if I use cre or ery

Comment: Use columnName ~* '\mquery\M'. \m matches start of word and \M matches end of word

Comment: Remember to use the parentheses in mybatis though